# Why didn't the tiny nanites fix the scars on Bloodshot's body?

Tags: valiant-comics, bloodshot-2020

Why didn't the tiny nanites fix the scars on Bloodshot's shoulder?

[image: Still of Bloodshot from the back, with red scars visible on his right shoulder and surrounding area]

Comment: I haven't seen the film yet, but aren't those scars from before he gets the nanite infusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The nanites in Bloodshot's body focus on protecting his vital organs of the body.

In an [interview](https://www.inverse.com/entertainment/scientific-reason-why-vin-diesel-skin-changes-in-bloodshot) with **Inverse**, *Bloodshot*'s director Dave Wilson confirms this.

> He [Wilson] describes the nanites as like a computer, which can overheat when it multitasks. "If the nanites are clustering, if you're being shot at and nanites are rushing all over your body to fix your vital organs, think of it as a computer system that is multitasking. **It is de-prioritizing functions of your body that are not vital to your survival, so your skin's pigment is not necessary to survive**."

So, since healing Garrison's scars are not vital for his survival, the nanites do not heal them.